# Previous submitted InfoPath form disappears in form library

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, list-item

I'm working in SharePoint 2013 (Office 365).

I have created an InfoPath form and publish it into the SharePoint site.

When I submit a new record it will be submitted successfully. But if I add another record then the previous record disappeares and the only the new record shows.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must submit the form with unique file name to avoid replacing the previous submitted form.

For a detailed explanation on how you can set unique file name please refer this article:

[Submitting an InfoPath Form to SharePoint with a Unique Filename](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37093/Submitting-an-InfoPath-Form-to-SharePoint-with-a-U)

Comment: Thanks for Your help. I give the rule for the form name at submit data connection. It will work successfully. But i give the rule for auto id generation(automatically increment).

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. No issues, you may use id in the file name. You may even use current system time. The conclusion is the file name must be unique whenever a new record is submitted. Please mark as answer if reply answers or resolve your query. Thanks

Comment: i give the rule for auto id generation(automatically increment). If i give that rule then the form will not submit. If i remove the rule then it will submit and show all the records. But i need both the function. I want the id automatically generate when the submit button click. Please give me any idea. I send the rule for auto id please check it. 1) Add the data connection for retrieve the ID of the form. 2) Add the action rule in submit options. Rule1: Query data:Retrieve Id. Rule 2: Set the fields value i.e TxtId=count(ID)+1 Rule3: Submit data.